# D3 Pie Chart new path values not being calculated after update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a very straightforward data structure where I want to have a D3 Donut Chart update based on a different key/value pair in the same object. Here is the data:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Bernie Sanders',
        name2: 'Jesus Christ',
        color: '#0362ad',
        state: 3.55,
        national: 4.88
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Donald Trump',
        name2: 'Miley Cyrus',
        color: '#f0a611',
        state: 1.36,
        national: 2.65
    }
]
```

I'm setting up my pie chart in the following way:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value( function(d) { return d.state });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 30)
    .innerRadius(radius - 80);

var paths = chart.selectAll('g')
    .data(pie(data), function(d) { return d.data.id })
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'arc')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (radius - margin.left) + ',' + (radius - margin.top) + ')');

var arcs = paths.append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .style('fill', function(d) { return d.data.color; });
```

I have an `update()` function in which I'm trying to change the Donut Chart values to show the `national` value rather than the `state` value.

```
// "which" is equal to 'state' or 'national'
function update(which) {

    // change location of values
    pie.value( function(d) { return d[which] );

    // compute new angles
    paths.data(pie(data));

    // update arcs
    arcs.attr('d', arc);
};
```

My arcs are not properly updating, and when I log them to the console, the `__data__` property still shows the value and angles for the initialized property (`d.state`).

How can properly compute the new paths for each arc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle transition scenario for the paths like so:

```js
(function() {

  var data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bernie Sanders',
    name2: 'Jesus Christ',
    color: '#0362ad',
    state: 3.55,
    national: 4.88
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Donald Trump',
    name2: 'Miley Cyrus',
    color: '#f0a611',
    state: 1.36,
    national: 2.65
  }]

  var svgElement = $("#piechart");
  var width = svgElement.width();
  var height = svgElement.height();
  var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  var chart = d3.select("#piechart");

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.state
    });

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 30)
    .innerRadius(radius - 80);

  chart.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'arc')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (radius) + ',' + (radius) + ')');

  var paths = chart.select('g').selectAll('path')
    .data(pie(data), function(d) {
      return d.data.id
    });

  paths.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .style('fill', function(d) {
      return d.data.color;
    })

  // which is equal to 'state' or 'national'
  function update(which) {

    pie.value(function(d) {
        return d[which]
      });

    paths.data(pie(data), function(d) {
        return d.data.id
      });

    paths.transition()      
      .duration(1000)
      .attr('d', arc)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return d.data.color;
      });

  };

  $("#stateButton").click(function() {
    update("state");
  });
  $("#nationalButton").click(function() {
    update("national");
  });

})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="stateButton">State</button>
<button id="nationalButton">National</button>
<svg id="piechart"></svg>
```

Comment: There aren't any scenarios that require entering or exiting elements, the number of elements are static with the only difference being the values bound to the data. I *only* want to update the existing pie chart with the new values, not append/remove paths each time.

Comment: It will only add and remove paths if the data changes, if you know the data will never change then you don't need the exit scenario, you will still need enter and transition though.

Comment: Is it necessary to include `d3.svg.arc()` and `d3.layout.pie()` declarations within the update function? Isn't this redundant?